# Библиотеки для чтения .xlsx файлов

Tags: java, xlsx

Мне срочно (в ближайшие часы) нужно переписать модуль на Java, который читает `.xlsx` файлы. До этого использовал *Apache POI*, но он крашиться на Android 4.2.2. Попытался использовать *JSpreadsheet*, но библиотека платная, а бесплатная — без нужного функционала.

Какие существуют библиотеки для чтения `.xlsx` файлов на Java (желательно — на Android, но не суть)?

Comment: На enSO такой же вопрос закрыли за некорректность, хотя и написал, что срочно. Все-таки не зря некоторых пендо... американцев стукачами называют...

Comment: Немного поздновато, но вдруг понадобится. Вы пробовали использовать [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j)? Примеры кода на [github](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/src/samples/xlsx4j/org/xlsx4j/samples)

Comment: @user3841429, пробовал. Там тоже что-то не так с Android'ом (или я до конца не разобрался, спешил все-таки).

Answer (score 2):

Единственный разумный вариант, который я нашел. Это использование Google Drive Sheet API.